# Android Studio - Gradle build times extremely slow caused by authenticated repo at top of repo list

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Posting/Answering this one for others as it caused me a lot of grief

My build times were going up to 4 minutes when they were usually 10-15 seconds, and none of the answers on any of the other threads were solving my problem.

My gradle file had an authenticated repo

```
repositories {

maven {
    credentials {
        username "${artifactory_user}"
        password "${artifactory_password}"
    }
    url "${artifactory_url}"
}

mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
```

The ordering of this was the problem (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by moving the authenticated portion to the bottom

```
repositories {

mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }

maven {
    credentials {
        username "${artifactory_user}"
        password "${artifactory_password}"
    }
    url "${artifactory_url}"
}
}
```

My current theory is that it was attempting to authenticate with the special URL for every single dependency before not finding it, timing out, and moving onto the next repo list.

I didn't see anything apparent in my logs indicating a time out.

Comment: Yes, I believe that Gradle goes down the list of repositories and checks them one by one for each dependency, so since it was checking the authenticated (slow) one first, this theory makes sense

Answer (score 1):

To speed up gradle build time.

- Make it work offline from Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle.
- Enable instant run (Enabled by defualt) from Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Instant Run.
- Do not terminate your emulator/device you are testing on.
- If you are testing on real Android device, do not let device screen go off to make android studio able to hotswap changes.